Grammar Structure with Present Participle
I got this sentence:

Wir analysieren deine Haut in Echtzeit, basierend auf modernsten Deep-Learning Algorithmen.

Its meaning is not a problem. In English, it can be translated as:

We analyze your skin in real time, basing/(based?) on modern Deep-Learning algorithm.

The "basing on..." is, as my understanding, a compact form of relative clause:

We analyze your skin in real time, which is based on modern Deep-Learning algorithm.

The "which" here refers to the entire phrase "We analyze your skin in real time".
Question: I failed to identify this grammar structure name (in both English and German): "..., basing on...". What is it? In comparison to English, it looks like this structure is much less used in German. Is that correct?

Just as an aside and unrelated to matters language: I'd like to call bullshit on the sentence! "Echtzeit"/"realtime" is an attribute which means that a system finishes a given task in some defined time, regardless of its complexity. Usually this is needed because input happens at a defined rate and constantly and the output has to match this. Example: taking dictation needs the writer to write as fast as the speaker speaks, regardless of the words being complicated or not. Note: "realtime" is not "fast", just that the output speed matches the input speed.

"Deep Learning" is all the rage, but "realtime" it is exactly NOT. "Algorithms" are neither "realtime" nor "not realtime", they simply don't have any such attribute at all. The implementation of an algorithm may be realtime (while another may not). So, this sentence looks like a buch of unrelated buzzwords lumped together and in fact making no sense at all.

The construction is not a relative clause.
basierend is the so-called "Partizip I", or "Partizip Präsens Aktiv", the present participle. The participle phrase basierend auf modernsten Deep-Learning Algorithmen is an attribute to the verbal phrase Wir analysieren deine Haut.
The English translation would read

Based on Deep Learning algorithms, we analyze your skin.

In English, this is a participle clause. In German, participle clauses exist. They are, however, used to express the temporal relation between the action in the participle clause and the action in the main clause -- present participle if the main clause action and the participle clause action happen at the same time, past participle if the action in the participle clause happens prior to the action in the main clause.
This, however, is not the case here. The participle construction is just an attribute to the verbal phrase, specifying it in more detail, similar to in Echtzeit.
In German, we use the present participle for this attribute, whereas English does not have this construction, and uses a participle clause with the past participle instead (don't ask me why). Literally, the German construction would translate to basing on... -- this would be wrong English.
On a side note: This nuance is the reason why I would consider the punctuation in the quoted sentence wrong (according to current official rules). Because this is a mere attribute, the comma is not supposed to be there in German (one of the rare occasions, where English has a comma and German doesn't). This kind of comma in this position is becoming a more and more common occurrence though, and I expect this to be considered correct during my lifetime. I reckon this trend is due to the influence of the punctuation in the English participle clause.
